# Linear control vs non linear control?

Tags: control, control-system

Do linear control come under category of classical control or non classical control?  And simliarly what will be category of non linear control? Will it come under category of classical control or non classical control?

Comment: These are orthogonal concepts. Classical vs modern control theory are different in the mathematical representations of the systems. Linear or non-linear. Pretty much summarized here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_control_theory#Classical_vs_modern

Comment: Linear is classical control, nonlinear is a newer field. I almost had a emphasis in controls

Comment: Hm. Are you the same person who asked this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/466284/classical-control-vs-non-classical-control Or you guys are having an exam or something?